# Why am I getting "redux-persist/createPersistoid: error serializing state"?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-persist

I have no idea why I'm getting this error. there's no file referenced no line referenced. I only know the action thats executed which results in the error.

The full error:

```
console.error "redux-persist/createPersistoid: error serializing
state", TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.
```

Here is the action that causes the error:

```
export const loadInitialDiscover = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: types.DISCOVER_LOADING });
        return getNewest(dispatch);
    };
};
const getNewest = (dispatch) => {
    return firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .where('role', '==', 'a')
        .where('active', '==', true)
        .orderBy('createdAt')
        .limit(10)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            const newest = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((queryDocSnapshot) => {
                const profile = queryDocSnapshot.data();
                newest.push(profile);
            });
            dispatch({ type: types.LOAD_NEWEST, payload: newest });
        })
        .catch((err) => loadFail(dispatch, err.message));
};
```

implementation of action in screen:

```
componentDidMount () {
    //console.log('INITIAL REDUX STATE: ' + JSON.stringify(this.props.newest));
    this.props.newest == null ? this.props.loadInitialDiscover() : null;
}
```

**notice this .stringify() is commented out**

Ive removed literally any and every existing `JSON.stringify`, deleted build folder, restarted bundler, restarted simulator. the error persists.

here is relevant reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    newest: null,
    loading: false,
    error: ''
};
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.DISCOVER_LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
                error: ''
            };
        case types.LOAD_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.info
            };
        case types.LOAD_NEWEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: '',
                newest: action.payload
            };
   }
}
```

and here's the persist config:

```
const persistAuthConfig = {
    key: 'auth',
    storage: AsyncStorage
};
const persistUserConfig = {
    key: 'user',
    storage: AsyncStorage
};

const persistDiscoverConfig = {
    key: 'discover',
    storage: AsyncStorage
};

const AppReducer = combineReducers({
    auth: persistReducer(persistAuthConfig, AuthReducer),
    user: persistReducer(persistUserConfig, UserReducer),
    discover: persistReducer(persistDiscoverConfig, DiscoverReducer)
});

export default AppReducer;
```

How do I get this error gone?

Answer (score 0):

The Firestore query response contains cyclic data (ref parameter) that is not possible to serialised by JSON.stringify hence the error from Redux-Persist, (yes; redux-persist use it under the hood). Just remove the `ref` parameter containing the cyclic data from all the objects inserted into the array `newest` array.
Also, do a check on other parameters that cannot be serialised by JSON.stringify like `ref`.
 The below may help you to achieve this:-

```
const newest = []; querySnapshot.forEach((queryDocSnapshot) => { 
const profile = queryDocSnapshot.data();
const {ref, ...profileSerialisable} = profile;
newest.push(profileSerialisable); 
});
```

Please refer [here](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/644#issuecomment-381333151) for more discussions based on this.